# sync local nongithub repository with github repository

Tags: git, github

I have a GitHub repository and have made amendments to this repository on a machine and uploaded the lasted version to google drive. Now I have a new machine, and I want GitHub repository to be updated as well.

I am thinking of first clone the GitHub repository and then compare each file of it with the latest version on google drive and replace those old files and then commit.

Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: did you upload a whole folder (including .git directory?)

Comment: I do have a .git directory, but I checked that and find out that all visible files' "last modified date" is last year, but I just edited those codes last month

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have `.git` folder uploaded to Google Drive, you're in a good situation. You copied the repository, not just files. So you can keep working as it was a regular clone of your repo.

Just download the folder with your project to your new computer, open your git client, pull changes from the remote, resolve merge conflicts, if any. And push it back.